# Canvas (Круг) низкого разрешения. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Для рисования квадрата использую замену **ImageView** на нарисованный **Круг (Rectangle)**.
Вот мой код для создания ImageView и рисования круга:

```
imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setId(R.id.imageViewCircle);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ((RelativeLayout)swipe).addView(imageView);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCircle);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 40, paint);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Вот что  у меня выходит:
[(Посмотрите Скриншот)](https://pp.userapi.com/c841629/v841629315/614db/oKuVan7ddZE.jpg)

Comment: А в чем проблема? Что рисуете, то и получаете :)

Comment: В чём проблема-то, что Вы хотите сделать, что не так? Просто показать круг можно несколькими способами и рисование битмапа не самый лучший.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже ImageView масштабирует вашу маленькую картинку на весь экран.

Попробуйте установить `imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER)`

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ. Но я разобрался сам.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам просто нужна "плавность" в границах круга - используйте сглаживание для кисти,которой рисуете:

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

Для сглаживания текста:

```
paint.setSubpixelText(true);
```

Но учтите, что нагрузка на устройство увеличивается

А если вам просто нужен круг на фоне кнопки, то лучше создать xml файл, например yelow_circle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FFFF00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

а кнопке преписать этот background

Comment: он использовал сглаживание в конструкторе Paint

Comment: Немного не то. Но спасибо, что потрудились!